# batch script to copy script files ending with .1.tst

Tags: batch-file

Hi i am new to batch scripting and i have to run a sanity test for that i have to copy all the basic script files to a folder. All the basic script files will be ending with

> `.1.tst`.

I have used the below code

```
for /r C:\ %f in (*.tst) do @copy "%f" D:\pictures\
```

but not working as expected.So i am not able to get all the files ending with

> .1.tst.

could anyone help-me out.

Comment: What happens if you change `(*.tst)` to `(*.1.tst)`?

Comment: can't replicate. Can you give an example of a missing file?

Comment: Double the `%` signs like `%%f`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set src_folder=C:\Users\Mallik\Desktop\
set dst_folder=C:\Users\Mallik\Desktop\abc\

rem /Y Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.
xcopy %src_folder%*.1.txt %dst_folder% /y
```

xcopy could do it easily.

---

Updated: (for **recursively** searching file with certain extension)

The code below will recursively search abc folder on desktop,

and copy all files end with .1.txt to ouput folder.

```
@echo off
set src_folder=C:\Users\Mallik\Desktop\abc\
set dst_folder=C:\Users\Mallik\Desktop\output\

cd %src_folder%
call :searchFile
goto :eof

:searchFile
for %%f in (*.1.txt) do xcopy %%f %dst_folder%
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    cd %%d
    call :searchFile
    cd ..
)
exit /b

rem dst_folder should not be under src_folder, 
rem otherwise warning "File cannot be copied onto itself"
rem removed /Y option in xcopy to prevent same name file be overwrited.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Anson thanks for the reply. I have used the script but it works for one file but i have multiple folders and multiple files

Comment: More details are need. Is it recursively iterating all folders and files, and return all files end with certain extension to one folder?